# Weka Classifier Accuracy

Tags: java, classification, weka, svm, naivebayes

I've got 73,841 instances of data, from 17 classes, that I am using to train a classifier with WEKA.  The data has been filtered using FFT, and each instance has three points.

```
I.e. 85724.5409, 40953.2485, 3204935, 4539024.002345, ?/class
```

I've tried three classifiers: SMO/J48/Naive Bayes.

The SMO/Naive Bayes are achieving accuracy rates of 16%

But the J48 classifier is producing accuracy rates of 98/99%.

Questions:

1. Can I safely assume that the J48 classifier is making some sort of mistake?
   How can two results be so similar, and the other completely different?
2. What can I do to increase the accuracy? Are there too many classes, are the classes simply not separable?

Thanks

Comment: Please post an mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Think I've made it a bit better?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly think the output of the Decision Tree is inaccurate.

Can you provide the tree generated or the top 10 nodes to see what is the exact problem.

Here are some of the measures I suggest to improve accuracy.

- **Class size**: 17 classes is indeed big. Try to reduce by merging similar classes. (Only to be done if it doesnt affect the scope of the project.)
- **Non-Liner Classifier**: Since you are having 17 classes a linear classifier like Naive Bayes/Decision Tree wont be enough. Did you try any non-linear SVM or ensemble learning like Random Forest. If enough data set is present for each of the 17 class then HMM will be a good choice for better classification.

Thanks,
Aravi